# How to find $f$ for a symmetric bilinear form?

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let's say we have the symmetric matrix:$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&2 \\ 2&0 \end{array}\right)$$

How do I find the symmetric bilinear form of this $A$?

Answer (score 2):

The bilinear form $B$ that this matrix represents is given by $$B(u,v) = u^TAv = \sum_i \sum_j A_{i,j}u_iv_j$$

---

**EDIT:**

To give a little more information, a [bilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form) is a function from a vector space $V$ to its field of scalars $K$, $B:V \times V \rightarrow K$ which is linear in each argument:

- $B(u_1+u_2,v) = B(u_1,v) + B(u_2,v)$
- $B(u,v_1+v_2) = B(u,v_1) + B(u,v_2)$
- $\alpha B(u,v) = B(\alpha u,v) + B(u,\alpha v), \alpha \in K$

Given a basis of $V$, $\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$, a bilinear form can always be represented by a matrix by examining how it acts on the basis vectors:

- define $B(e_i,e_j) = A_{i,j}$

$$B(u,v) = B(\sum_i u_ie_i,\sum_j v_je_j )$$
$$ = \sum_i u_i B(e_i,\sum_j v_je_j)$$
$$ = \sum_i \sum_j u_i v_j B(e_i,e_j)$$
$$ = \sum_i \sum_j u_i v_j A_{i,j}$$
$$ = u^TAv$$

---

Examples:

The determinant of a $2 \times 2 $ matrix is a bilinear form over its column vectors (in general it is an $n$-linear form over the columns of an $n \times n$ matrix).

The [first fundamental form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_fundamental_form), which is like a sort of generalized dot product that lets you measure angles and distances on curved surfaces, is also a bilinear form.

Comment: May I ask what the biliean form represents, @eigenchris?

Comment: @Khallil pardon but I don't understand your question. I just know that any bilinear form over a finite dimensional vector space can be represented as a matrix, using the formula above. Is there something I should clarify?

Comment: Oh, it's just that I've not seen bilinear forms before so I was wondering what it can be used to describe.

Comment: @Khallil I see. I'll edit my answer to give a little more context.

Answer (score 1):

Bilinear forms are exactly those linear maps taking two vectors to a scalars, so this form of $A$ maps to exactly one of those linear maps, as denoted by @Eigenchris.

For further 'meaning', consider the bilinear form $u^TAv$. $Av$ is just some new vector $v'$, so we have $u^Tv'$, which is just the dot product between $u$ and $v'$. So first $v$ gets mapped to some different vector by a linear transformation, then we take the dot product between that vector and $u$.